# Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: 'Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 2 row(s)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I received this error once I try to update table with the same value (`carNumber`), my condition is to update where the actual return date field is null.

For some reason it's look like the query return 2 rows, but actually there is only one. I'm using EF. This is the function:

[the error - print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJbfD.png)

Code:

```
public void updateStatus(int carNumber1, string actualDate1)
{
        DateTime accReturn = DateTime.Parse(actualDate1);

        var orderCar1 =  db.CarRentalFields.FirstOrDefault(carNum =>
        (carNum.CarNumber == carNumber1 && carNum.ActualReturnDate == null));

    orderCar1.ActualReturnDate = accReturn;
             
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

The error happens when trying to call `db.saveChanges()`.

[the table from the db, the car number is 1000 - print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpUz4.png)

[modelBuilder.Entity pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSFzc.png)

Please let me know how can I solve this issue.

Comment: Do you have any primary key for this table?

Comment: You post only several records. I am afraid that there is one more record with carNum.CarNumber == carNumber1 && carNum.ActualReturnDate

Comment: Have you told EF that car number is the primary key when that's actually not the case?

Comment: the pk fot that table is: start_day, return_date ,user_id, car_number. all those 4 together.

Comment: @CaiusJard I am not sure about  car_number as a primary key, it can only happen if primary key is composed

Comment: The way you configured your entity's primary key does not conform to the key in the database. Correct your EDMX, attributes or ModelBuilder. If you don't know how, show the relevant parts of it (without your night filter over the screenshots, please).

Comment: @elirans to use several dates as a primary key not is the best idea.

Comment: @Serge, it seems to me that EF is making a query like `UPDATE t SET x = @y WHERE car_number = @z` expecting it to update one record (because it think car number is PK) and it's getting a surprise when two records update.. in my mind that translates to there being no PK or PK in db being compound but in either case EF has been told wrong thing about PK in table

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm not really understand where to find the  ModelBuilder.?

Comment: In Bricksburg. No wait, that's the Master Builder. I don't know, you either use an EDMX or a DbContext with an OnModelCreating() or attributes, or any combination thereof.

Comment: I'm using DbContext. i edit my question  and add print screen.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when EF cannot resolve the PK for your entity. In most cases for simple entities, EF conventions can work out the PK, but in your case you are using a composite key so this needs to be configured. Depending on how you are mapping your entities you can do this either in:

- an EDMX
- in the DbContext.OnModelCreating
- using an `EntityTypeConfiguration` declaration
- using attributes within the entity itself

Since we don't know how your entities are configured, you can verify this as the cause by using the attribute approach within your entity as a test. If you are using an EDMX the entity classes will be generated so you will want to replace this with configuration within the EDMX. (Cannot really help you there because I don't use the dang things :D )

You will probably have something like:

```
public class CarRentalFields
{
    [Column("start_day")]
    public DateTime StartDay { get; set; }
    [Column("return_date")]
    public DateTime ReturnDate { get; set; }
    [Column("user_id")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Column("car_number")]
    public DateTime CarNumber { get; set; }
    
    // ... more columns...
}
```

You may even have a `[Key]` attribute on one of these fields, such as CarNumber. If there is a PK mapped in the entity the issue is that it isn't specific enough to uniquely identify the row. When EF goes to update one entity, it is checking for, and expecting to update only one row in the table. It's finding more than one row will be affected so it fails.

Append the attributes for the `[Key]` with the column order so it is recognized as a composite key.

```
public class CarRentalFields
{
    [Key, Column(Name="start_day", Order=1)]
    public DateTime StartDay { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Name="return_date", Order=2)]
    public DateTime ReturnDate { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Name="user_id", Order=3)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Name="car_number", Order=4)]
    public DateTime CarNumber { get; set; }
    
    // ... more columns...
}
```

Provided these 4 columns are guaranteed to be a unique constraint on the table, EF will be satisfied when only one row is updated when it builds it's UPDATE SQL statement.

Note again that if this works and you are using an EDMX, you will need to review and modify your EDMX mapping to make the appropriate changes since that entity class could be regenerated, losing your extra attributes. (I believe the generated entity classes from an EDMX have a comment header warning you that it is a generated class, so that is an indicator to watch out for.)

Update:
My primary suspect in this would be that the table does not actually have a matching PK defined, either running a different PK combination, or more likely no PK given the nature of those fields. EF can operated on tables that have no PK defined, but it does require a Key definition that ensures records can be uniquely identified. The error you are seeing happens when that key definition is not unique enough. (I.e. if you are updating car 1, and selecting a row that has:
car_number = 1, start_day = 2021-11-21, return_day = 2021-11-22, user_id = 0   The issue is that more than one row has that combination in the DB. If the DB you are checking doesn't have more than one matching row then your application is almost certainly pointing at a different database than you are checking.

Things you can do to verify this:

1. get the runtime connection string and see if it matches the DB you are checking:

Before you run your query, add the following:

```
// EF6
var connectionString = db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
// EF Core 5
var connectionString = db.Database.GetConnectionString();
```

2. Have a look at the data you are actually querying:

.

```
var cars =  db.CarRentalFields.Where(carNum =>
    (carNum.CarNumber == carNumber1 && carNum.ActualReturnDate == null)).ToList();
```

While this query might return only 1 record, that is not the cause of the problem. What you want is the CarNumber, StartDate, ReturnDate, and UserId for this record:

```
var car =  db.CarRentalFields
    .Where(carNum => carNum.CarNumber == carNumber1 
        && carNum.ActualReturnDate == null)
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        x.CarNumber,
        x.StartDay,
        x.ReturnDate,
        x.UserId
    }).Single(); // Expect our 1 record here...
var cars = db.CarRentalFields
    .Where(x => x.CarNumber == car.CarNumber
        && x.StartDay == car.StartDay
        && x.ReturnDate == car.ReturnDate
        && x.UserId == car.UserId)
    .ToList(); // Get rows that match our returned Key fields.
```

These queries select the assumed PK values for the car record you mean to update, then search cars for matching records with the expected Key fields. My money would be on that while the top query returns 1 record, the bottom query returns two rows, meaning while only 1 record has a #null ActualReturnDate value, your Key is not unique enough for the contents of this table.

Comment: i'm using contex, did you saw my print screen of the model builder?

Comment: Yes, ok that's using the DbContext's OnModelCreating modelBuilder, so the Key is being defined. The next thing to check will be whether those columns match the PK /w unique constraint in your corresponding database. If not, that key may need to be expanded. Composite keys should be avoided as much as possible as they make setting up relationships a lot more work. You can also use a profiler to capture the proposed update statement, then convert that into a simple SELECT to see what rows are returned. For some reason more than one rows are coming back.

Comment: Another thing to check is whether at runtime the application is hitting the same database as what you are checking. The data you are checking might appear unique enough if the DB is not enforcing a unique constraint on those columns, but the database being pointed to at runtime has duplicate rows.

Comment: same error occur using your solution, did I need to change my function also?  @Steve Py

Comment: Capture the SQL being generated and run on the database. I typically use a Profiler for this, so for SQL Server and SSMS, under Tools\SQL Profiler. Run that against your DB, then execute your query. You can use a breakpoint in your application just before the SaveChanges, then clear the profiler output before resuming to clean out previous noise and find your UPDATE statement.

Comment: Also, can you post the table designer output for your table? Does the table have an actual PK set with those 4 columns?

Comment: I added to the answer above to include steps to double-check the connection string as well as verify in the data whether there are duplicate key values.

Comment: I tried your solution. first thing it look's like you miss some '=' in the cars var. second thing- when i try to make the update:  cars.ActualReturnDate = acctualDate1;  i got an error cs1061.

Comment: That code is to test your data scenario. "cars" will be a List of cars. For your original code to have worked that list should contain only 1 car, the code is to check how many cars are returned for that combination. Does cars contain 1 car or 2 cars? I returned the cars rather than just do a Count so you can inspect exactly which records are returned and compare that to the database records you think it should be reading. If it contains 2 cars then your database allows for and has more than one record with that specific combination of key values. (your key is not specific enough)

Answer (score 0):

problem solved by add a new column to the car_rental_fields table, id column that include Identity.
as I understand from here and from the web, there is an issue with complicated pk.
in my solution the id isn't a primary key, but it's make the logic for linq to update the correct column.
thanks' for all the people that involved in this issue.